# Exercise 1.11 in the book The Theory of Finite Groups, An Introduction.

Tags: group-theory

> Suppose that $A\neq 1$, and $A\cap A^g=1$ for all $g\in G\backslash A$. Then
> $$
> \Bigg\vert{\bigcup}_\limits{g\in G}{A^g}\Bigg\vert\geq\dfrac{|G|}{2}+1.
> $$

I do really find no clue in solving this small problem. Any help is sincerely appreciated. Thank you!

**PS:** It’s on the page 10 of the famous book *The Theory of Finite Groups, An Introduction*. Berlin: Springer, 2004. [Or the original edition *Kurzweil H, Stellmacher B. Theorie der endlichen Gruppen, Einführung.* Berlin: Springer, 1998]. I failed to find any published solutions even hints of the exercises in this book on the Internet. It is a trouble for me. Is anywhere any kind of resource?

Comment: You have $|G|/|A|$ sets of size $|A|$ which all intersect in a given element (the identity), and have no other element in common. What is the size of the union? (This is a set theory/basic counting question, nothing to do with group theory.)

Comment: @verret I got it: $\dfrac{|G|}{|A|}\cdot (|A|-1)+1=|G|-\dfrac{|G|}{|A|}+1\geq |G|-\dfrac{|G|}{2}+1=\dfrac{|G|}{2}+1$, where $|A|\geq 2.$ But how to explain the absurd result above?

Comment: That's right. I have no idea how you got the above. Why is the size of the conjugacy class $|G|-|A|+1$?

Comment: @verret We have got the conclusion that”for all $g,k\in G\backslash A,g\neq k,A^g\neq A^k$”, then the size of the conjugate class is $|G|-|A|+1$.

Comment: It is not true that if $g,k\in G\setminus A$ and $g\neq k$, then $A^g\neq A^k$. What is true is that $A^g=A^k$ if and only if $gk^{-1}\in A$. (Or $g^{-1}k\in A$, depending on which convention you use for conjugacy.) Try to prove this, I think it will clarify things for you.

Comment: @verret , thank you for answering my questions. Um, I think that's not difficult: $A^g=A^k\Leftrightarrow A^{(gk^{-1})}=A\Leftrightarrow gk^{-1}\in N_G(A)=A.$Now I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: Exactly. Note that $gk^{-1}\in A$ if and only if $Ag=Ak$, so the conjugates are in natural correspondence with cosets of $A$.

Comment: @verret : )Removed.But now I get a little confused about why all conjugate subgroups pairwise intersect trivially. I want to say that with the correspondence, but that also seems insufficient : (

Comment: Suppose that $A^h$ and $A^k$ are two distinct conjugates, that is, $A^h\neq A^k$. Then $A^{hk^{-1}}\neq A$ so, by hypothesis, $A\cap A^{hk^{-1}}=1$ so $A^k\cap A^h=1$.

Comment: @verret : )Thanks.I feel like a fool.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is saying that conjugate subgroups of $A$ pairwise intersect trivially. (Can you see why?) Now, try to count how many conjugates there are, and use inclusion-exclusion to calculate the size of the union of the conjugates. (You can actually compute it exactly in terms of $|G|$ and $|A|$.)

Comment: Thank you!Yes, I think I know why the conjugate subgroups parewise intersect trivially(I think it in this way:because $A\cap A^g=1$, for all $k\in G,\, A^{k}\cap A^{(gk)}=1^{k}=1.$Can I do it in that way?). But I don’t quite know how to compute it. Does it need the property of normalizer that $(G:N_G(A))$equals to the size of the conjugate class?

Answer (score 1):

Since we have solved the problem, let me sort it out.

1. $~\forall g\in G\backslash\,A,\,A\cap A^g=1$, $A\neq A^g$, that is to say, $\forall g\in G\backslash\,A,\, g\not\in N_G(A)$.Hence, $N_G(A)=A.$
2. In terms of the property of normalizer, the class number is $|G:N_G(A)|$, thereby the number is $|G:A|=\dfrac{|G|}{|A|}$.
3. Each conjugate has the same size of distinct elements: If $A^g\neq A^k,$ then $A^{gk^{-1}}\neq A$, by hypothesis, $A^{gk^{-1}}\cap A=1$, thereby, $A^{g}\cap A^k=1^k=1.$ That is to say, the conjugate subgroups intersect trivially, each distinct conjugcy class has $(|A|-1)$ distinct elements, and their common element is $1$.
4. We now can calculate the exact size of the union of the conjugates. We have $\dfrac{|G|}{|A|}$ different conjugates, each conjugate has $(|A|-1)$ distinct elements, and intersection is always $1$, we have: $$\dfrac{|G|}{|A|}\cdot (|A|-1)+1=|G|-\dfrac{|G|}{|A|}+1\geq |G|-\dfrac{|G|}{2}+1=\dfrac{|G|}{2}+1$$, where $|A|\geq 2.$

Problem solved. Thanks for @verret !